# Make `createsuperuser` work with custom / non-trivial user model

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

In the "create super user" step of `python manage.py syncdb`, I'd like to be able to specify

1. E-mail
2. Password
3. First name
4. Middle name (blank is acceptable)
5. Last name
6. Phone

My "user model" is:

```
class Account(auth_models.AbstractBaseUser):
    email       = models.EmailField(unique = True, db_index = True)
    created_on  = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    person      = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    def get_full_name(self):
        ...
    def get_short_name(self):
        ...
    objects = AccountManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

and the `Person` model is:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name         = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    is_staff     = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    phone        = models.CharField(max_length = 16, blank = True)
```

My custom account "manager" naturally needs to have all these informations, so what I did was:

```
def create_user(self, email, password, name, phone):
    normalized_email = self.normalize_email(email)
    person = Person(
        name = name,
        phone = phone
    )
    person.save()
    account = Account(email = normalized_email, person = person)
    account.set_password(password)
    account.save()
    return account
```

At creation of course it only asks me about the email and password while completely ignoring the `Person` model that also needs to be populated.

How can I make it so that all 6 fields are required in the "create super user" step?

<sub>To those who are going to question the idea of having `Account` and `Person` separated: a single `Person` can have multiple `Account`s associated with it; it's called a "one-to-many relationship" between `Person` and `Account`; It's perfectly legal, check it with your lawyer.</sub>

---

I tried to go with adding `person` to the `REQUIRED_FIELDS` but that, as specified in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS):

> Since there is no way to pass model instances during the createsuperuser prompt, expect the user to enter the value of to_field value (the primary_key by default) of an existing instance.

requires a `Person` ID which I don't have (I need to create the person first).

Specifying:

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['person.name', ...]
```

is not supported (the error says `person.name` is not a field of `Account`).

Comment: The easy solution could be set Person to `null=True` or provide a default value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a method called `create_superuser()` that should look like this:

`def create_superuser(self, email, password, name, phone):
     user = self.create_user(
         email=email,
         password=password,
         name = name,
         phone = phone
     )
     user.save(using=self._db)
     return user`

This way `REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['person']` works for me.